# DBAmp delete a row from Account table

Tags: dbamp

can some to tell how I can to see all foreign keys for specific table in DBAmp.

I would like to delete a row from Account table:

```
delete from SLFORCE_DEV...account where Id='002x020030Vf644A2Z'
```

**Error:** *Your attempt to delete [username] could not
be completed because it is associated with the following payment
methods.: [some value]*

So is there a way to list all foreign keys, then to be able to delete specific row.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it if you have access to the Salesforce Org, is to look at the fields on the Account object and look at the Field dependencies and/or the Controlling Fields. Or even use the Schema Builder that is standard in Salesforce.  It will show all the objects as a UML type diagram.  Some might not be displayed, so you will have to select any that you may think are related.

I don't know if you are using the Force.com plugin for Eclipse, but if you are using it there is a really useful schema view that will be towards the bottom of all the files in the solution explorer.  It will show all the relationships and even let you run queries from it.

Other than that, there isn't a real easy way that I've found.